# SYN Cookie Implementation in Linux

Tags: networking, tcp, linux-kernel

Following is a snippet of code from linux kernel. It includes the seq of client in syn-cookie. The problem with this scheme is that if the first packet from client get's dropped, the connection will get reset on the second packet. My question is why do you need to include the client sequence number in the SYN cookie?

```
static __u32 secure_tcp_syn_cookie(__be32 saddr, __be32 daddr, __be16 sport,
        __be16 dport, __u32 sseq, __u32 count,
        __u32 data)
{

    /*
     * Compute the secure sequence number.
     * The output should be:
     *   HASH(sec1,saddr,sport,daddr,dport,sec1) + sseq + (count * 2^24)
     *      + (HASH(sec2,saddr,sport,daddr,dport,count,sec2) % 2^24).
     * Where sseq is their sequence number and count increases every
     * minute by 1.
     * As an extra hack, we add a small "data" value that encodes the
     * MSS into the second hash value.
     */

    return (cookie_hash(saddr, daddr, sport, dport, 0, 0) +
            sseq + (count << COOKIEBITS) +
            ((cookie_hash(saddr, daddr, sport, dport, count, 1) + data)
                    & COOKIEMASK));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The sseq number is included in the hashing operation to have more state information in the cookie. Its a general notion that the hash becomes more robust when multiple disjoint informations are cooked together. And, regarding your worry about conn being reset in the second syn case, yes it will happen and that is the intention. More than that, the syn cookie is normally enabled only when the server is detected under threat.

Please read here large level of details about syn-cookie implementation and why the sseq number is one of the input param.

http://www.cisco.com/web/about/ac123/ac147/archived_issues/ipj_9-4/syn_flooding_attacks.html

Comment: You are right that if the first packet get's dropped the connection has to be reset, because there is no way one can compress the whole 32-bit sequence number information in the cookie and hence it can't be regenerated. Another good reason is pointed by Robert Love, as a response to the same question I posted on Quora (http://www.quora.com/Linux-Kernel/Why-does-Linuxs-SYN-cookie-implementation-use-the-initial-client-sequence-number-in-generating-the-cookie/answer/Robert-Love-1)